# No module named 'azure.profiles' - Python

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to execute below line of code:

```
from azure.keyvault.secrets import SecretClient
```

which internally runs the below code and comes up with an error:

```
from azure.profiles import KnownProfiles, ProfileDefinition
```

Below is the error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'azure.profiles'
```

Doing "pip freeze" in my environment gives me following modules:

```
azure-common==1.1.8
azure-core==1.16.0
azure-identity==1.6.0
azure-keyvault==4.1.0
azure-keyvault-certificates==4.3.0
azure-keyvault-keys==4.4.0
azure-keyvault-secrets==4.3.0
azure-mgmt-core==1.3.0
azure-mgmt-storage==18.0.0
azure-nspkg==2.0.0
azure-storage-blob==12.8.0
azure-storage-common==0.37.1
azure-storage-nspkg==2.0.0
```

Obviously, I do not see anything related to azure-profiles. Below git link directs to installing azure-mgmt-storage to solve the issue, but it didnt help.

https://gitmemory.com/issue/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/8497/551170157

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I think the reason is that version of azure-common is too low.
Please try the latest version.

```
pip uninstall azure-common
```

then

```
pip install azure-common
```